# STM32 UART DMA can receive first time correct then it receive nothing

Tags: stm32, uart, dma

I'm trying to use dma with uart in stm32f746 nucleo.

In receiving mode I can receive correct data in first use. When i try to receive again, receiving buffer doesn't change its initial values before receiving although I can get receive complete signal callback every time.

```c
    /*   Main Loop */
    while(1)
      {
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_PORT,LED_GREEN);      // Led Example 
        
            HAL_Delay(200);
            
            pRxData[0]=5;
            pRxData[1]=0;
    // HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&UartHandle,pRxData,2);
       if( HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&UartHandle,pRxData,2)==HAL_OK);  // UART-DMA-IT Example
            {
                while (UartReady != SET)                     // wait for msg len
                {
                     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_PORT,LED_GREEN,1);
                     HAL_Delay(20);
                     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_PORT,LED_GREEN,0);
                     HAL_Delay(400); 
                } 
                UartReady = RESET;                        // reset transmition flag
                LEN = pRxData[0]+pRxData[1]*256;             // calc msg length
                
                if ( LEN > 0 )
                {
                    pTxData[0]= 25;//LEN;                            // ACK
                    //HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&UartHandle,pTxData,1);
                    if(HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&UartHandle,pTxData,1)==HAL_OK);
                    {
                    
                        while (UartReady != SET) 
                        {   
                         HAL_Delay(1);
                        } 
                        
                        UartReady = RESET;
                        if(HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&UartHandle,pRxData,LEN)==HAL_OK)
                        {
                        //HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&UartHandle,pRxData,LEN); 
                            while (UartReady != SET)                  // waiting loop for msg
                            { 
                                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_PORT,LED_GREEN,1);
                                HAL_Delay(300);
                                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_PORT,LED_GREEN,0);
                                HAL_Delay(50);
                                
                            } 
                            
                            UartReady = RESET;
                            
                                if (MBU_StrCompareNC(pRxData,"LED_ON_BLUE",LEN)==0)
                                {
                                    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_PORT,LED_BLUE,1); 
                                }
                                
                                if (MBU_StrCompareNC(pRxData,"LED_OFF_BLUE",LEN)==0)
                                {
                                    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_PORT,LED_BLUE,0); 
                                }
                                if (MBU_StrCompareNC(pRxData,"LED_ON_RED",LEN)==0)
                                {
                                    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_PORT,LED_RED,1); 
                                }
                                
                                if (MBU_StrCompareNC(pRxData,"LED_OFF_RED",LEN)==0)
                                {
                                    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_PORT,LED_RED,0); 
                                }
                                
                        }
                            
                     
                        HAL_UART_Abort(&UartHandle);
                    }
                }
             }
     }
    }
```

Comment: If you use DMA transfer for RX, you rather want to use a circular buffer and then check regularly if sufficient data for an entire message has arrived. If you setup DMA for only 2 bytes and then call HAL_Delay(400), you likely receive 2 bytes and the rest is lost as the sender keeps sending but your code is stuck in HAL_Delay and not receiving anymore. I also not the semicolons on the same line as `if (...` (twice). That's likely an programming error.

Comment: thanks for try it is ok after  I disabled d-cache I have no idea about cache problems